# How to add in URL redirection in App browser?

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

I have done this code to detect FB In-App browser in my website:- My I know how to add in redirection `window.location.href = "http://www.example123website.com";` if detected FB-In App browser?

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>App Link</title>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
   function isFacebookApp() {
    var ua = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;
     window.location.href = "http://www.example123website.com";

    return (ua.indexOf("FBAN") > -1) || (ua.indexOf("FBAV") > -1);

}

    </script>


</head>
<body>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what do you mean.. if `isFacebookApp` succeed then redirect?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code:

if `isFacebookApp` succeed:

```
function isFacebookApp() {
            var ua = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;
            var s  = (ua.indexOf("FBAN") > -1) || (ua.indexOf("FBAV") > -1) ;
             if(s> -1  &&  s!=false)
            {
                window.location.href = "http://www.example123website.com";
            }
        }
```